# How create 'tar.gz' package without root directory?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I need create tar.gz package without root directory.
Now I have tree:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mrayl.png)

Result example:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfE9V.png)

I useed gradle task, which created tar.gz package with cfg directory:

```
plugins.withType(DistributionPlugin) {
    distTar() {
        into('cfg') { from 'cfg' }
            compression = Compression.GZIP
            extension = 'tar.gz'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to remove the root level directory from the produced archive, you can use [Tar.eachFile](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Tar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Tar:eachFile(groovy.lang.Closure)) API to change/alter the target file paths, as follows:

```
distTar {
    // Alter file path to remove root level directory
    eachFile { file ->
        String path = file.relativePath
        file.setPath(path.substring(path.indexOf("/")+1, path.length()))
    }
}
```

(I did not find any method or property from the Tar task API to implement this in a nicer way)